# Adb push error: closed

Tags: adb, google-pixel-2

I want to move the firmware to the phone’s memory in order to install it on the device via TWRP, since the computer does not have enough power to install the firmware in time, there is a problem with the waiting time. How I can install android 13 to pixel 2

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. As of current wording, I'm afraid this question might be considered [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) with "install Android 13 to Pixel 2" as X and "move the firmware to the phone's memory" as Y. Could you [edit] and explain in more detail of what you're trying to do, or otherwise restate the question clearly? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: make sure `/data` is successfully decrypted and mounted (or factory reset to remove encryption). try USB 2.0 Port/Hub or different cable. try from `adb sideload` or MicroSD Card/USB OTG pendrive. try [`adb usb`](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-adb-returning-error-closed.2272731) command

Answer (score -2):

Use [google android flash tool](https://flash.android.com/release/13.0.0) then find your device image [here](https://developers.google.com/android/images) there is a

> "taimen" for Pixel 2 XL

and

> "walleye" for Pixel 2

on their list. I hope this answers your question

Comment: [Pixel 2 has reached end-of-life](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705) since a few years ago, I doubt it has an Android 13 image there.